# Printing array array to selected object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an object that has multiple items which, have an array array of values.  I also have a page which has a series of div elements which allows a user to click on them and show the array array associated with the div they clicked.  However, this is not happening, when I click on the div, which houses the object item, I'm getting nothing but undefined logs.  Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var Alerts = {
    apu: [["APU Power Fail", "APU[1]"], ["APU Power Fault", "APU[2]"], ["APU Generator Fail", "APU[3]"], ["APU High Oil Temperature", "APU[4]"], ["APU Hot Start", "APU[5]"], ["APU Loss Overspeed Protection", "APU[6]"], ["APU Starter Engaged", "APU[7]"], ["APU Fire", "APU[8]"], ["APU Fails Bite Check", "APU[9]"], ["APU Door Fails to Open", "APU[10]"], ["APU No Flame", "APU[11]"], ["Left Fire Bottle Discharge", "APU[12]"]],

    avionics: [["ADS 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[1]"], ["ADS 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[2]"], ["ADS 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[3]"], ["AP 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[4]"], ["AP 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[5]"], ["Autopilots Fail", "AVIONICS[6]"], ["Baroset 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[7]"], ["Baroset 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[8]"], ["Baroset 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[9]"], ["CCD 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[10]"], ["CCD  2 Fail", "AVIONICS[11]"], ["Heading Comparison Monitor", "AVIONICS[12]"], ["Heading and Roll Comparison Monitor", "AVIONICS[13]"], ["Display Controller 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[14]"], ["Display Controller 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[15]"], ["IRS 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[16]"], ["IRS 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[17]"], ["IRS 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[18]"], ["Glideslope Antenna Fail", "AVIONICS[19]"], ["MAU 1A Fail", "AVIONICS[20]"], ["MAU 1B Fail", "AVIONICS[21]"], ["MAU 2A Fail", "AVIONICS[22]"], ["MAU 2B Fail", "AVIONICS[23]"], ["MAU 3A Fail", "AVIONICS[24]"], ["MAU 3B Fail", "AVIONICS[25]"], ["MRC 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[26]"], ["MRC 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[27]"], ["GPS Degrade", "AVIONICS[28]"], ["GPS #1 Fail", "AVIONICS[28]"], ["GPS #2 Fail", "AVIONICS[30]"], ["Display Unit 1 Fail", "AVIONICS[31]"], ["Display Unit 2 Fail", "AVIONICS[32]"], ["Display Unit 3 Fail", "AVIONICS[33]"], ["Display Unit 4 Fail", "AVIONICS[34]"], ["GPS - Unable RNP", "AVIONICS[35]"]]
}
for(var array in Alerts){
    var system = array.toUpperCase();
    $("#form_emergencies").append("<div class='systems' id='" +array +"'><div class='select_box'></div><h2> " +system +"</h2></div>");

    $(".systems").on("click", function(){
        $.each(Alerts[array], function(ind,item){
            console.log(Alerts[array].item);
        })
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've got the habit of creating my objects with capitol letters, but that's not why my script is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice of variable names is quite confusing.

Let's start with `for(var array in Alerts)`, in this statement `array` is not actually an array, it's simply refers to the key, which in turns is a system in your domain, therefore I would change `array` to `systemKey`.

Then, you go on and attach handlers inside the loop. This code is problematic because the second system will end up having two click handlers attached.

```
for(var systemKey in Alerts){
    var system = systemKey.toUpperCase();
    $("#form_emergencies").append("<div class='systems' id='" +systemKey +"'><div class='select_box'></div><h2> " +system +"</h2></div>");
}

//Notice I used this.id rather than array
$(".systems").on("click", function(){
    $.each(Alerts[this.id], function(ind,item){
        //...
    })
})
```

Finally, `console.log(Alerts[array].item);` is wrong, just put `console.log(item);`

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much.  Also, did you use `$.each(Alerts[this.id], function(ind,item)` to find the value of the id of the clicked div?

Comment: @Robert Yes, since `this` refers to the clicked `.system` div element. I would use a data attribute like `data-system-key` rather than `id` btw. It's more expressive and less limitating. You rarely want an `id` attribute on dynamically generated DOM elements.

Comment: would using `data-id` and then in the click event doing `variable = $(this).data("id"); then iterating on the variable work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/njo1dppw/4/)

```
for(var array in Alerts){
    var system = array.toUpperCase();
    $("#form_emergencies").append("<div class='systems' id='" +array +"'><div class='select_box'></div><h2> " +system +"</h2></div>");    
}


$(".systems").on("click", function(){
     var keyVal = $(this).attr("id");
     $.each(Alerts[keyVal], function(ind,item){
         $.each(item, function(ind2,item2){
               console.log(Alerts[keyVal][ind][ind2]);
         });
    })
});
```